# How to play an animation on hover and pause when hover is not active

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a button that I want to rotate when the mouse hovers over it. However, while the spinning works when the mouse enters, it also spins when the mouse leaves. Here is what I mean:

```css
button {
  transition: transform 1.2s linear;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button>X</button>
```

Is there any way to just make the mouse spin when the mouse enters?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `animation` instead of `transition` and make use of [`animation-play-state`<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state)

```css
button{
  animation: rotate360 1.2s linear infinite;  /* animation set */
  animation-play-state: paused;               /* ...but paused */
}
button:hover{
  animation-play-state: running;              /* Run on hover! */
}
@keyframes rotate360 {
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }           
}
```

```html
<button>X</button>
```

Comment: hi , I just asked a question related to this code. I would be grateful if you can take a look at it. Question Link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75808462/12909051

Answer (score 3):

Try this snippet

```css
button:hover {
  transition: transform 1.2s linear;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button>
X
</button>
```

Comment: That works! I was so close. Is there any way to make the button stay in the position it was when the user's mouse leaves?

Comment: @MarksCode Not possible with CSS I guess. Are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: I am! I was looking for that

Answer (score 3):

In previous examples when mouse leaves an element the transition resets to first state very suddenly. It's better to make the transition play back.

In this example button is animated when mouse is hovering and when mouse left it:

```css
button {
   transition: transform 1.2s linear;
}
button:hover {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button>
X
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 1.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<button>
X
</button>
```