# 2 css animation call for 1 element

Tags: css, css-animations

Why does the animation only work when element appear but not when you hover?

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  background: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 4;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

span:hover {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px dodgerblue
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px transparent
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px transparent
  }
}
```

```html
<span>
  Test
</span>
```

https://codepen.io/umasterov/pen/XWJGLQV

if you remove the animation when it appears, the hover animation works

Comment: is this fit your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888453/how-to-play-animation-on-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

Duplicating the animation

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  background: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 4;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

span:hover {
  animation-name: pulse2;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px dodgerblue
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px transparent
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px transparent
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px dodgerblue
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px transparent
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px transparent
  }
}
```

```html
<span>
  Test
</span>
```

Using pseudo-element

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 4;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

span:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 dodgerblue
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px transparent
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent
  }
}
```

```html
<span>
  Test
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think option with duplication is better.

Comment: @IvanU, happy to help.

Comment: Can't one animation be used twice according by the specification?

Comment: @IvanU, one animation can be used several times on the same element if its `animation-play-state` would reset on hover. When the animation has played, its state is `stopped` and I'm not sure if we can reset it on hover using CSS only. That's why I suggested the options above.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take your animation off the normal state

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
span {
  background: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
span:hover {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px dodgerblue}
  50% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px transparent}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px transparent}
}
```