# Conditionally change className to css module (React)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make an animation play when the user is hovering over the navbar on my website. I'm trying to accomplish this by having the css module change depending on whether the mouse is over the navbar or not. I'm struggling to figure out why this code is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Navbar.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "../styles/Navbar.module.css";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [className, setClassName] = useState("line-after");
  return (
    <div
      className="navbar"
      onMouseEnter={() => setClassName("line::before")}
      onMouseLeave={() => setClassName("line-after")}
    >
      <nav>
        <Link to="/about" className="home-page">
          Bob
          <br />
          Jones
        </Link>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about" className="about-page">
              About
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/resume" className="resume-page">
              Resume
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact" className="contact-page">
              Contact
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div className={styles.className}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Css Module:

```
.line::before { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 55px;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    animation-name: animate;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.line-after { 
    margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
    position: relative; 
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
     }
}
```

I'm changing the state of the className when the mouse leaves and enters the navbar. It says that my state variable className is never being used, however so I believe that is the problems. Not sure how to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this without using react logic at all, you can simply use CSS animations (like you are currently doing) and CSS pseudo-classes (hover in this case) instead of dinamically changing the class of the element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Check if this is useful to you [How to play an animation on hover and pause when hover is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888453/how-to-play-an-animation-on-hover-and-pause-when-hover-is-not-active)